# Solving system if equations containing trigonometric functions with Ti-Nspire

Tags: trigonometry, problem-solving, systems-of-equations

In trying to solve the following system of equation:

$20000\times9.81+a\cos b=0$

$a\sin b=6.17\times20000$

Find $a$ and $b$ .

It gives me something containing "n2" in bold and I don't know why?

$a=-231780.07/(-1)^{n2}$

$b=(180*(n2*pi-0.56143476))/pi$

How do I get the right answer? Thanks

Comment: If you have a calculator, you can solve for each of $sinb,cosb$, and then use $sin^2b+cos^2b=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

solve(20000*9.81*a*cos(b)=0 and a*sin(b)=6.17*20000,a,b)

Answer should yield this:

a=((−123400.)/(cos(3.14*n1))) and b=3.14*(n1-0.5)

Comment: I'd suggest that you read this page on how to properly format your answer in LaTeX. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

Compare with standard solution of polar /cartesian  coordinate relations and interpret the differences. Let

$$a/20000= \alpha, 9.81= g;$$

$$ \left(g +\alpha \cos b=0, -6.17+ \alpha \sin b=0 \right)$$

Eliminate b ;

$$ \alpha= \sqrt{g^2+ 6.17^2}; $$

Multiply this by 20000 to get a ;

and

$$ b=\sin^{-1}\dfrac{6.17 }{\alpha}.$$